# How is `(( ... ))` different from `( ... )`?

Tags: shell, unix, switch-statement, arithmetic-expressions, subshell

I wrote the following code:

```
case "$2"  in  '+') ((res = $1 + $2 ));;

               '-') ((res = $1 - $2 ));;
esac

echo $res
```

Usage example: `./"*filename*" 2 + 3`

If I use double parentheses,

```
((res = $1 + $2 ))
```

then the result gets printed. However, if I use single parentheses

```
(res = $1 + $2 )
```

then nothing gets printed. What is the difference between `( )` and `(( ))`?

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: `((...))` is for [arithmetic expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04), whereas `(...)` runs the enclosed command in a subshell, which does not affect its parent shell.

Comment: Also, note that, in your example the second parameter (`$2`) is the operator, not the second operand. Accordingly, you probably want `((res = $1 + $3))` and `((res = $1 - $3))`, here.

Comment: @Jubobs Those comments could be posted as an answer.

Comment: What about reading the shell manual? It explains `( ... )` and `(( ... ))`. On Linux that would probably be `man bash`.

Answer (score 2):

The double parentheses `(( ... ))` are for [arithmetic expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04), whereas the single parentheses `( ... )` run the enclosed command in a [subshell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_12), which has its own scope and doesn't affect the environment of its parent shell.

Here, with `(res = $1 + $2)`, even if variable `res` is successfully assigned a value in the subshell, `res` remains unset in the parent shell, which explains why nothing gets printed. You want to use `(( ... ))`, in this particular case.

Besides, note that, in your example, the second parameter, `$2`, is the operator, not the second operand. Accordingly, you need to use `((res = $1 + $3))` and `((res = $1 - $3))`, instead.

Additionally, for robustness, you may want to make sure that

- the number of arguments is valid,
- the first and third arguments are valid integers,
- the second parameter is a valid arithmetic operator (`+` or `-`, here),
- etc.

Finally, for improved portability across different shells, prefer `printf` over `echo`.

## Corrected and improved code

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# foo

# Custom error function
die() {
  printf "%s\n" "$1" 1>&2 ;
  exit 1;
}

# Function that returns an exit status of
#   0 if its first argument is a valid integer,
#   1 otherwise.
is_integer() {
  [ "$1" -eq 0 -o "$1" -ne 0 ] >/dev/null 2>&1
}

# Check that the number of argument is 3
[ "$#" -eq 3 ] || die "invalid number of arguments"

# Check that the operands are valid integers
is_integer "$1" || die "invalid first operand"
is_integer "$3" || die "invalid second operand"

# If the second argument is a valid operator, assign res accordingly;
# otherwise, die.
case "$2" in
  '+')
    ((res = $1 + $3))
    ;;
  '-')
    ((res = $1 - $3))
    ;;
  *)
    die "invalid operator"
    ;;
esac

printf "%s\n" "$res"
```

## Tests

After making the script (called "foo") executable, by running

```sh
chmod u+x foo
```

I get the following results

```sh
$ ./foo -18 + 5
-13
$ ./foo 9 - 4
5
$ ./foo a + 2
invalid first operand
$ ./foo -18 + c
invalid second operand
$ ./foo 3 / 4
invalid operator
```

Comment: Applause for using printf instead of echo.